# Proving $f(x) = x$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

I'm trying to prove that $f(x) = x$ is integrable, using [this definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882770/why-this-definition-of-integrability-by-sup-and-inf-integrals-is-necessary). I've seen somewhere that an equivalent way to prove it is to show that given $\epsilon>0$ we can always have:

$$S(f,P)-s(f,P) <\epsilon$$

Where, duo to the nature of the function $f$, we have:

$$S(f,P) = \sum t_i(t_i-t_{i-1}) = \sum t_i^2-\sum t_i t_{i-1}$$
$$s(f,P) = \sum t_{i-1}(t_i-t_{i-1}) = \sum t_{i-1}t_i-\sum t_{i-1}^2$$

$$S(f,P)-s(f,P) = \sum t_i^2-\sum t_i t_{i-1} -\left(\sum t_{i-1}t_i-\sum t_{i-1}^2\right) =$$
$$\sum t_i^2-2\sum t_it_{i-1}+\sum t_{i-1}^2$$

I don't see how it helps. I know that the sum is in the interval $[0,1]$ so it might help using this. I might take the partition somehow related to the $\epsilon$ so this sum above always end up less than $\epsilon$ but I have no idea of how to do it

Comment: You can define the Riemann-integrability as $\lim_{n\to\infty}S(f,P_n)-s(f,P_n)=0$, where $P_n$ is a partition with $n$ parts.

Comment: "an equivalent way to prove it is to show that given $\epsilon>0$ we can always have:
$S(f,P)-s(f,P) <\epsilon$": the true statement is "given $\epsilon>0$, **there's a $\delta_{\epsilon}>0$ s.t. for all partition $P$ of mesh $<\delta_{\epsilon}$**, we have $S(f,P)-s(f,P) <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is 
$$S(f,P)-s(f,P)=\sum(t_i-t_{i-1})^2.$$
Given $\varepsilon>0$, pick $N$ so that $N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.  Now choose the partition $P=\{0,\frac{1}{N},\ldots,\frac{N-1}{N},1\}$.  Then we have
$$S(f,P)-s(f,P)=\sum\left(\frac{i}{N}-\frac{i-1}{N}\right)^2=\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{align*}
\sum t_i^2-2\sum t_it_{i-1}+\sum t_{i-1}^2 
  & = \sum t_i^2-2  t_it_{i-1} + t_{i-1}^2 \\
  & = \sum (t_{i} - t_{i-1})^{2}
\end{align*}
and you can always use the uniform partition