# Riemann and Darboux Integral of a product of two functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I'm studying the Darboux definition of integrability, which I completely explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882770/why-this-definition-of-integrability-by-sup-and-inf-integrals-is-necessary). There's an exercise that asks me to prove that the Darboux Integrability is equivalent to Riemann Integrability, but this Riemann integral is defined as the following:

It first defines a 'pointed' partition (I don't know how to say it in ensligh) by the following: a 'pointed' partition $[a,b]$ is a pair $P^*=(E,ξ)$, where $P=\{t_0, t_1, \cdots, t_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and $ξ = (ξ_1, \cdots, ξ_n)$ is a list of $n$ chosen numbers such that $t_{i-1}\le ξ_i\le t_i$ for each $i=1,\cdots ,n$.

Now, the Riemann Integral is defined as:

$$\sum(f,P^*) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(ξ_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})$$

(I didn't understand the notation for the left hand side of the equation, by the way)

Finally, I'm asked to prove the following: given $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ integrable functions, for the entire partition $P=\{t_0, \cdots, t_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ let $P^* = (P,ξ)$ and $P^{\#} = (P, η)$ be pointed partitions of $P$, then:

$$\lim_{|P|\to 0}\sum f(ξ_i)g(η_i)(t_i-t_{i-1}) = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \ dx$$

I guess here I need to prove that the Riemann Integral of the product of two functions if the darboux integral of $f(x)g(x)$, but it seems too obvious, I just need to verify that $f,g$ are integrable, then their product is too, isn't it? I'm pretty sure this should be a hard question. Is there another interpretation that I'm missing?

Comment: The notation $\sum (f, P^{*})$ is called a Riemann sum for $f$ over a pointed/tagged partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ and Riemann integral is then defined as the limit of such sums as the norm $|P|$ of the partition $P$ tends to $0$. Most books also use the notation $S(f, P^{*})$ instead of $\sum(f, P^{*})$. Note that this is the original definition of integral given by Bernhard Riemann.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have discussed the equivalence of definitions of Riemann integral based on Darboux sums and Riemann sums in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834341/72031) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1255344/72031).

The idea is that the Riemann sums are technically difficult to handle because of the arbitrary nature of $\xi_{i}$ in sub-interval $[t_{i - 1}, t_{i}]$ of a partition $T = \{t_{0}, t_{1}, t_{2}, \ldots, t_{n}\}$ of $[a, b]$. Hence the Darboux sums are used which replace the $f(\xi_{i})$ with supremum and infimum of $f$ on $[t_{i - 1}, t_{i}]$ and thereby remove dependency on the arbitrary $\xi_{i}$.

Now I come to your question. Suppose $f, g$ are Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$. Then it is possible to prove that their product $fg$ is also Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$. By definition of Riemann integral as a limit of Riemann sums we see that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx = \lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(\xi_{i})g(\xi_{i})(t_{i} - t_{i - 1})\tag{1}$$ where the notation is taken from your question. You are now asked to prove that the points $\xi_{i}$ need not necessarily chosen to be same for $f$ and $g$ so that we can use $\xi_{i}$ for $f$ and another set of points $\eta_{i}$ for $g$. This is correct and we prove it below.

Note that
\begin{align}
|\Delta| &= \left|\lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(\xi_{i})g(\xi_{i})(t_{i} - t_{i - 1}) - \lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(\xi_{i})g(\eta_{i})(t_{i} - t_{i - 1})\right|\notag\\
&= \left|\lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(\xi_{i})\{g(\xi_{i}) - g(\eta_{i})\}(t_{i} - t_{i - 1})\right|\notag\\
&\leq M\lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}|g(\xi_{i}) - g(\eta_{i})|(t_{i} - t_{i - 1})\notag\\
&\leq M\lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\{M_{i}(g) - m_{i}(g)\}(t_{i} - t_{i - 1})\notag\\
&= M\lim_{|P| \to 0}\{U(P, g) - L(P, g)\}\tag{2}\\
&= M \cdot 0\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
where $M$ is some bound for $|f|$ on $[a, b]$ and $M_{i}(g)$ and $m_{i}(g)$ are supremum and infimum of $g$ on $[t_{i - 1}, t_{i}]$. Hence $\Delta = 0$ and it follows that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx = \lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(\xi_{i})g(\xi_{i})(t_{i} - t_{i - 1}) = \lim_{|P| \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(\xi_{i})g(\eta_{i})(t_{i} - t_{i - 1})\tag{3}$$

The limit in $(2)$ is $0$ and it is somewhat difficult to prove that it is $0$. I have proved it in the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834341/72031) as the following theorem:

> **Integrability Condition 2** *A function $f$ bounded on $[a, b]$ is Riemann integrable over $[a, b]$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a number $\delta > 0$ such that $$U(P, f) - L(P, f) < \epsilon$$ whenever norm $|P| < \delta$.*

**Note**: The result in question is called Bliss' Theorem which was proved by G. A. Bliss (see [his paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1968041)) as an alternative to a more general result called [Duhamel Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3081325/72031).

Comment: I'm confused about your usage of the limit notation, $\lim\limits_{ |P| \to 0^+}$ (I've taken the liberty to assume that you meant the right hand limit as $|P|>0$). In any case, how does that limit make sense? $P$, a sequence, is not a function of $|P|$, positive real number (since two different partitions can have the same norm) so shouldn't $\lim\limits_{|P|\to 0^+} U(P,f)= U(P,f)$?

Comment: @William: please see the definition given in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2047959/72031