# If $f$ is integrable, then $|f|$ is integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

In order to prove that if $f(x)$ is integrable, then $|f(x)|$ is, I'm using the [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882770/why-this-definition-of-integrability-by-sup-and-inf-integrals-is-necessary) that $f$ is integrable $\iff \forall \epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that

$$S(f,P)-s(f,P)<\epsilon$$

but

$$S(f, P) = \sum M_i(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$$
$$s(f, P) = \sum m_i(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$$

What I need to prove is that

$$S(f,P)-s(f,P)<\epsilon \implies S(|f|,P)-s(|f|,P)<\epsilon$$

I cannot find an obvious relation in order to prove it. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Whqat happens to $M_i$, $m_i$ when replacing $f$ with $|f|$?

Comment: $sup|f|\ge sup f$?

Comment: In fact if $g$ is any function continuous on a closed interval containing the range of $f,$ then $g \circ f$ is Riemann integrable. $g(x)=|x|$ is a special case of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: $||M_i|-|m_i|| \le |M_i-m_i|$

Comment: And I need to use that $M_i-m_i\ge 0$ right?

Comment: Yes. $M_i \ge m_i$ for each subinterval.